# Console command runing from Cron job failing after Craft update

Tags: plugin-development, database, updates

I have had a custom console command running fine for several months now which sent out reminder emails to users when there accounts are about to expire.

After the latest Craft update (I believe) it stopped working. Here is the error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'users.locked' in 'field list'
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.locked' in 'field list'' in CDbCommand.php:543
```

The lines of code from the plugin service which cause the error are:

```
$user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);

$user_criteria->userExpiryDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 days"));

$users = $user_criteria->find();
```

Basically it fails when running the find() method.

Strangely I haven't managed to replicate the error on my local machine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Do you have a 'locked' column in your craft_users table? That table's schema changed within the last several months. Maybe your database and your code are out of sync?

Comment: Hi Brad, I've just checked the table and there is no locked column. What would be the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Check the schemaVersion and build in your `craft/app/Info.php` and file and compare that to you the schemaVersion and build in the `craft_info` table in the database. If those don't match then your database schema is out of sync with the code you're running.

Comment: On the live site in the Info.php it is on 2.3.1 but on the database it is 2.1.2. Somebody else applied the update on the live site without my knowledge so I'm not sure whether it was successful. When I backed up the live database and imported it to my local server the schemas matched (both on 2.3.1) which I can't seem to explain. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the build number in Info.php and the database?

Comment: In info.php the build is 2625 and in the database it is 2569

Comment: When you go to the control panel, are you not prompted to complete an upgrade?

Comment: No, which is what I would expect to happen and has happened in the past. I have also tried clicking check for updates and it says there is no more updates

Comment: If you want to send some CP/FTP/database credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can look into why it's not prompting to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a case of looking at the wrong database.  The version/build/schema numbers for the correct database were all in sync.